# cannot open source file "locale.h" (dependency of "iostream")

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I continue to run into this include error / cannot open source file. I have now also  tried resetting all of vs codes setting to default, but nothing I have tried has worked so far. Any advice on where to look would, or what's causing this would be extremely appreciated!

I have tried editing configurations in the json, adding to and editing the include paths and a few other long shot changes that I've come across on here.

I included a screen shot of the errors that I am currently encountering. I read somewhere that installing xcode fixed this issue for other people. But I don't use xcode, nor do I really want to.

My compiler is brew g++-11, I have also checked to make sure that the path in the json and the actual path match. I'm kind of at a loss what to do, I tried asking my professors today for help and they were just as lost. Any advice on where to look for a solution would be amazing.

[image]

I have also tried changing the include path from "${workspaceFolder}/**" to "${workspaceFolder}/inc". Which didn't work either.

Here is the current c_cpp_properties.json

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-11",
        "cStandard": "gnu17",
        "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

I also tried to check the intellisense extension settings, but that is admittedly a bit outside of my scope.

Comment: The error says the file doesn't exist, not that there's a problem with the contents of it. Double check that path in your screenshot. Make sure it's exactly correct. I don't know if Mac has case-sensitive filenames, but if so then double-check the casing as well.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Where are you seeing that the file doesn't exist? I don't understand exactly what it is you're saying, but I am definitely interested in hearing yours / any thoughts on it.

Comment: In the tooltip, I see "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open <your json file>".

Comment: Ah, my fault. I reset all the settings in VScode to default by removing the directory "$HOME/Library/ApplicationSupport/code". That fixed the failed to parse error, but I'm still getting the "#include errors detected: Please update your include path" error message.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your problem. They are harder to read, cannot be searched, and (as here) usually mean you just did a screenshot of your work-in-progress without attempting to write up a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Adding this to the include path fixed it:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1`

I got the path from running:
`gcc -v -E -x c++ -`

Which outputs information about your gcc compiler.
I'm on an M1 Mac running Monterey.

This is my vscode config:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

As you see, the compiler is homebrew but the include path is xcode.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this after some settings are changed. Listed as below for your reference.

- Compiler Path: /usr/bin/clang++
- IntelliSense mode: macos-clang-64

I don't know why. But it works.

BTW: my platform is Mac

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here is how I solved it :

- Open terminal, use `which XXX` where `XXX` is your compiler and copy the path
- On VSC go to Configuration -> "C_Cpp › Default: Compiler Path" and paste the path

It should now work, however I never used c_cpp_properties.json file.

Answer (score -1):

when this happened to me, I added the bin folder in which is in the compiler to system environment variables this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gb9e3m98avk) might help you

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the video you posted is for windows and I'm running into this issue on a mac.